# Seeking Uruguay or South America DEM or DTM?

Tags: data, dem, south-america, uruguay

Is there any DEM (Digital Elevation Model) or DTM (Digital Terrain Model) for Uruguay or South America?

I am aware of the Renare for Uruguay.

Comment: Are you wanting a free data source?

Answer (score 1):

You can download a 90-m resolution DEM from http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/download. It covers both Uruguay and all of South America.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. However keep in mind that the SRTM elevation data may contain off terrain objects.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the relatively new [MERIT-DEM](http://hydro.iis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~yamadai/MERIT_DEM/), which is mostly SRTM but heavily corrected (especially north of 60 degrees). You can download it in tiles. They also have corresponding hydrologic models ([MERIT-Hydro](http://hydro.iis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~yamadai/MERIT_Hydro/)) that include flow directions, flow accumulations, channel widths, height above nearest drainage, and a depression-filled DEM. All global.